# @OneToMany Spring Data JPA in SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE Does not get all data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this domain class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_purchase")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Purchase implements Serializable {

    public Purchase() {
    }

    public Purchase(Shop shop) {
        super();
        this.shop = shop;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = “shop_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    Shop shop;
…
}
```

and also

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “t_shop")
public class Shop implements Serializable {


    public Shop(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Purchase> purchases = new HashSet<Purchase>();

        …
}
```

and this method in the repository:

```
@Query("select shop from Shop shop left join shop.purchases where shop.id = ?1")
Shop shopPurchases (Long shopId);
```

then I created this Junit method:

```
@Test
public void testFindByShopIdWithPurchases () {

    Shop shop = new Shop ("Shop_NAME");

    shopService.save(shop);

    Purchase purchase1 = new Purchase(shop);
    Purchase purchase2 = new Purchase(shop);

    shop.getPurchases().add(purchase1);
    shop.getPurchases().add(purchase2);

    shopService.save(shop);

    Shop shopWithPurchases = shopService.findByShopIdWithPurchases(shop.getId());

    assertEquals (2, shopWithPurchases.getPurchases().size());


}
```

But it fails because it returns 1 purchase instead of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override equals for entities with generated id you need to handle the case where both ids are null. Otherwise the HashSet will treat the new entitites as equals and will only store one.

You can use the default equals in that case:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Purchase  other = (Purchase) obj;
    if(this.id == null) {
        if(other.id == null) {
            return super.equals(other);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return this.id.equals(other.id);
}
```